# Simple Vanilla JS game

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I tried write simple vanilla JS memories game. I have a problem when i tried use query selector for divs which are created in Square class. Console.log returns empty nodelist or array. I suspect this function is done before divs are created. How Can I gain this elementy by query selector or another method ?

```js
// CLASS SQUARE

export class Square {
    constructor (number,type,field) {
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.field = field;
        this.colors = ['red','red','blue','blue','orange','orange','green','green','gold','gold','pink','pink','cadetblue','cadetblue','purple','purple','beige','beige','cyan','cyan']
        this.divs = [];
    }
    creator() {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
            let create = document.createElement(this.type)
            this.field.appendChild(create)
            create.classList.add('square')
            create.setAttribute('id','square')
            this.divs.push(create);
            console.log(this.divs)
        }
   
    }
    addColor() {
        this.divs.forEach((div)=>{
            let chooseColor = Math.floor(Math.random()* this.colors.length);
            div.style.backgroundColor = this.colors[chooseColor]
            this.colors.splice(chooseColor,1)

        })
    }
    addShadow() {
        this.divs.forEach((div)=>{
            const shadow = () => {
            div.classList.add('shadow')
            }
            setTimeout(shadow,2000)
        })
    }
}

// CLASS SHADOW

export class Shadow  {
    constructor(shadowDivs) {
        this.shadowDivs = shadowDivs;
    }
    revealDiv() { // THERE IS MY PROBLEM
        this.shadowDivs.forEach((shadowDiv)=>{  
     
            shadowDiv.addEventListener('click',()=>{ 
                console.log(this.shadowDivs)
          
                shadowDiv.classList.remove('shadow')  
            })
        })
    }
}

//MAIN JS FILE

import { Square } from "./Square.js";
import { Shadow } from "./Shadow.js";


class Game {

    elements = {
        number: 20,
        type: 'div',
        field: document.getElementById('field'),
        divs: document.querySelectorAll('.shadow') //THERE I TRY GAIN ELEMENTS
    }

    init() {
      const squareCreator = new Square(this.elements.number,this.elements.type,this.elements.field);
      const shadows = new Shadow(this.elements.divs) // AND THERE I CREATE NEW SHADOW
      squareCreator.creator();
      squareCreator.addColor();
      squareCreator.addShadow();
     // squareCreator.revealDiv()
      shadows.revealDiv()

    }
}

const game = new Game();
game.init()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gameField" id='field'></div>



    <script src="js/script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```js
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  game.init(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but where I should put this event listener ?

Comment: Where ever you want. Always wait till the DOM is loaded.
or you can use defer property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

Remove the timeout

```
    addShadow() {
        this.divs.forEach((div)=>{
          div.classList.add('shadow')
        })
    }
```

Reorder the ini() and use the querySelector after the addShadow else there will be nothing to select.

```
    init() {
      const squareCreator = new Square(this.elements.number,this.elements.type,this.elements.field);
      squareCreator.creator();
      squareCreator.addColor();
      squareCreator.addShadow();
      const shadows = new Shadow(document.querySelectorAll('.shadow')) // AND THERE I CREATE NEW SHADOW
      shadows.revealDiv()
    }
```

Comment: I should replace my const variable by this set Timeout  ? I received type error becouse I try replace const value and when I change this variable to let, but still nothing happen

Comment: My bad, wrap the parts that needs the dom elements

Comment: still nothing :( maybe it's my bad in another part of code ? i wrap it as you say and put  squareCreator.creator(); outside this timeout

Comment: Haha. I see what is the issue. You are doint the querySelector before creating and adding the shadow class to the divs. Remove the setTimeout in addShadow, move Shadow initialization after addShadow in init() and use the querySelector after the classes as been added.

Comment: omg :D thanks for your time ! now I understand